# Linking with a newer library rather than an old one

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I am trying to compile the Point Cloud Library from source (http://pointclouds.org/). After running cmake and make, I receive the following linking error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary
../../lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7.2: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
```

As a newbie, I'm not sure what this error means, but I am assuming: the executable file `plc_convert_pcd_ascii_binary` which it is trying to build, needs to be linked to the library `libpcl_io.so.1.7.2`, but this library contains the function `png_set_longjump_fun`, and the definition of this function cannot be found?

So, I have tried looked at some similar questions on Stack Overflow, and it turns out that `png_set_longjump_fun` is contained in the `libpng` library, but was only introduced after `libpng-1.4.x`. After running `dpkg -l | grep libpng*`, I get the following output:

```
ii  libpng12-0:amd64                                      1.2.50-1ubuntu2                                     amd64        PNG library - runtime
ii  libpng12-dev                                          1.2.50-1ubuntu2                                     amd64        PNG library - development
```

So it looks like I need to upgrade from `libpng12-dev` to at least `libpng14-dev`. From the libpng website, I see that I can download the source for the latest version (but the latest version I can get through `apt-get` is only `libpng12-dev`). But I am worried that there may be some conflictions if I have one version installed via apt-get, and another version installed manually. However, uninstalling `libpng12-dev` may cause issues if there are packages which depend on this, but are not compatible with the newer version.

Therefore, what I would like to know, is whether I should uninstall/purge `libpng12-dev`, and then install the new version manually, or to simply install the new version whilst keeping the old version. And if I do the latter, how can I be sure that the PCL binary I am trying to compile, will link with this new library, rather than the old one?

Thanks :)

Comment: How did you obtain the source? I cloned it from the git repo this morning (`git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git`), and it seemed to link happily against libpng12.so.0 however the version of libpcl_io.so that it built is different (`libpcl_io.so.1.8` as opposed to your `libpcl_io.so.1.7.2`). Maybe worth trying the complete build again from git?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm running into the same problem.